# How to access Form textboxes inside EventHandler by string in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am using Visual Studio 2017. There is a form with textboxes. These textboxes need a refresh every 10 seconds. For achieving this I use a Timer event.

```csh
public partial class status_window : Form
{
    public status_window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        shutdown_button.Click += new EventHandler(shutdown_click);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = (1 * 10000); // 10 secs
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();

    }
}
```

The timer_tick function is member of the status_window class. Inside that eventhandler I can access the textboxes by their name as expected. But how to do that if the textbox "adress" is i variable. Look:

```csh
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Int32 unixtime = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;

    // for all boxes per exname
    for (int i = 0; i < something.Count() ; i++)
    {

        //  try to find textbox 1 -> embty result
        Console.WriteLine( this.Controls.Find("nam1_last_event", true) );
        Console.WriteLine( this.Controls.Find("nam2_last_event", true) );   //  also empty result

        //  this works and fills the formbox as ecxpected
        nam1_last_event.Text = "somevalue";
        nam1_event_count.Text = "anothervale";
        nam2_last_event.Text = "somemorevalue";
        nam2_event_count.Text = "andsoon";

        //  thats what i want later to use my for loop for those:
        //  something[i] exuals to nam1,nam2 and so on
        this.Controls.Find( String.Format("{0}_last_event", something[i].ToLower()) , true)[0].Text = "somevalue";  //  this fails cause array returned by find is empty
        this.Controls.Find(String.Format("{0}_last_event", ex_name.ToLower()), true)[0].Text = "anothervale";   //  same

    }

}
```

So I stuck here somehow limited by my own knowledge. Most results on Google suggest to use the controls Find Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var inPanel = this.Controls.Find("inPanel", true).OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault();
inPanel?.Text = "Found it";
```

Comment: How is this any different than what was tried by the OP other than throwing a `NullReferenceException` when an element is not found instead of an `IndexOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: Fixed the NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use equally name `nam1_last_event` as member of class `status_window` and name of control. Please check in designer if your control relay has name `nam1_last_event`.

Function `Controls.Find` use key which is value of property `Name` of control.

Comment: Do you mean this one? https://www2.pic-upload.de/img/33798040/Unbenannt.png

Comment: No this is separate property of control which is hidden in design mode. Please look in documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a list or Dictionary variable to save those textboxs, and get it in the timer_Tick.